# Trouble Accessing Internet through Wireless Router

Tags: internet, router, wireless-networking, troubleshooting, windows-2000

I'm having trouble accessing the internet. I can connect to my wireless router successfully, but I can not access the actual internet. However, other computers connected to the same network can. What are some potential problems?

Comment: Are the other computers also Win2k?

Comment: No, they're not. Two are Mac OS X, One is Vista.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into problems like this before, there are two likely culprits.

1. Make sure the Windows 2000 computer is set to obtain an IP via DHCP and that your encryption key is working. This is essential for DHCP functionality :

   [image]
2. If your router is using MAC Filtering, make sure to add your NIC's MAC to the allow list:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are associating correctly with the access point/proper SSID

second make sure you have an actual IP address on your internal network.  IPCONFIG /ALL is rather illustrative for this.  If you do not have an IP address then I would double check your encryption key because this can keep it from working.  If the encryption key is off, you will not get an IP address via DHCP.

If you do not have dhcp on your wireless segment you can always hard code an address on the same subnet.

The third thing I would check would be that your wireless access point is configured properly to point at your default gateway.  This should get you up and running.

Remember Ping is your friend and traceroute will also tell you many things in this type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Being that the computer is Win2k, I've found that some of the third-party programs to connect the computer wirelessly cause issues.  Check your third-party program to make sure that it has all of the information for the Gateway and DNS Server(s).

-JFV

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you are connecting to the router successfully, what do you mean? You can be connected but not be assigned a valid IP address -- you would have a 169.xxx address instead of the typical 192.168.xxx.xxx. If it is a 169 address then you probably are using the wrong encryption key.